# jQuery datepicker pass a date but will not drop down calendar

Tags: datepicker

Using PHP I pass in a default value to the jQuery datepicker, which works:

It comes in via AJAX
But when I first click on the input containing the date, I do not get the jQuery dropdown calendar.

On either side of the date input I have navigation arrows (buttons with onclick events) to go to the next date or the previous date which also work.   Once I do this, then clicking on the datepicker id will show the calendar.

I think it has something to do with focusing on that id, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I figured it out.  Since AJAX is involved, I hadn't been passing the datepicker code in the responseText section.  Once I did this, the initial click on the date field drops down the calendar.